# How to highlight behind text drawn by DrawTextEx

Tags: c#, gdi

For a custom control, I am using primarily [DrawThemeTextEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773317.aspx) (with [DrawTextEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162499.aspx) via ([TextRenderer.DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160657.aspx) as a fallback). I'm implementing an incremental search, where the user enters a search string and all matches are highlighted. In order to draw the highlight behind the text, I need to calculate the rectangle of each matching subrange of the drawn text.

I don't want to handle font kerning at the boundaries of the highlight, so I don't want to draw the text piecemeal. The aim is just getting the rectangle coordinates and drawing a styled rectangle.

What GDI function can I use to do this? I've searched all over. The closest GDI function I have found might be [GetCharacterPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144860.aspx) but it's not obvious to me from the documentation how I would even start using it.

I know that this must be built into Windows; textboxes have no problem finding and highlighting arbitrary ranges of drawn text. It must be exposed as an API somewhere, right? I have a strong dislike for GDI+'s text rendering and I don't want to introduce DirectX just to do something simple like this.

Comment: You need more pinvoke.  Call SetBkMode() to specific OPAQUE, SetBkColor() to specify the background color for the text.  What the TextRenderer class uses.

Comment: To clarify, only subranges will have a background color. The text may also wrap. I would like to avoid running my own trimming/wrapping algorithm and drawing the text piecemeal. Plus I would like to custom draw the rectangles.

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: How does SetBkMode help determine rectangle coordinates for subranges of text within the drawn text?

Comment: Of course, when you draw the individual subranges.  The thing you don't want to do but must do.  Use the DT_CALCRECT option.

Comment: Is that what the textbox control uses to get the coordinates of a character by the character's index within the text string?

Comment: You'll have to ask Microsoft, Edit control source is not public.  Nothing trivial about it.

Comment: I'm not going to draw individual subranges. I don't want sections of text moving back and forth as the highlight changes because of kerning issues at the range boundaries. The text will be drawn after the translucent rectangles are drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works well. I haven't added features to handle wrapping, but it handles horizontal and vertical alignment and ellipses with flying colours. If the highlight is partially cut off or missing, the entire ellipsis is highlighted.

This function may be a little naive in the big Unicode world, so it's probably worth looking into [Uniscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374093.aspx) at some point. Perhaps a more knowledgeable person could tell me what DrawText uses internally.

```
public static class TextUtils
{
    const TextFormatFlags AlignFlags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Right | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Bottom;
    const TextFormatFlags PaddingFlags = TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding;
    const TextFormatFlags EllipsisFlags = TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis | TextFormatFlags.WordEllipsis | TextFormatFlags.PathEllipsis;
    const TextFormatFlags CalcRectFlag = (TextFormatFlags)0x400;



    public static Rectangle GetHighlightRectangle(IDeviceContext dc, string text, int highlightStart, int highlightLength, Font font, Rectangle bounds, TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.SingleLine)
    {
        if ((flags & TextFormatFlags.SingleLine) == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("This method only handles single line highlights. Multiline text highlights may be composed of multiple rectangles.");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) throw new ArgumentException("Text must not be null or empty.", "text");
        if (highlightStart < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("highlightStart", highlightLength, "Highlight length must be greater than or equal to zero.");
        if (highlightLength <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("highlightLength", highlightLength, "Highlight length must be greater than zero.");
        if (highlightLength > text.Length - highlightStart) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("highlightLength", highlightLength, "Highlight length must be less than or equal to the length of the text minus the highlight start.");



        var drawTextParams = GetTextMargins(font, flags);

        Size totalSize;

        // Determine total size and adjust for cut-off highlight.
        // We need access to the modified string in case it was trimmed.
        // Unfortunately, TextFormatFlags.ModifyString can't be used with TextRenderer.MeasureText
        // so we'll have to roll our own.
        var hdc = dc.GetHdc();
        try
        {
            var modifiedText = new StringBuilder(text);
            var rectBounds = new RECT(0, 0, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

            var hFont = font.ToHfont();
            try
            {
                var oldFont = Gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
                try
                {
                    User32.DrawTextEx(hdc, modifiedText, modifiedText.Length, ref rectBounds, (flags & ~AlignFlags) | CalcRectFlag | TextFormatFlags.ModifyString, ref drawTextParams);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Gdi32.SelectObject(hdc, oldFont);  
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Gdi32.DeleteObject(hFont);
            }

            totalSize = new Size(rectBounds.Right - rectBounds.Left, rectBounds.Bottom - rectBounds.Top);

            // drawTextParams.uiLengthDrawn may be equal to text.Length even if an ellipsis was applied
            for (var i = 0; i < drawTextParams.uiLengthDrawn; i++)
                if (modifiedText[i] != text[i])
                {
                    var unchangedLength = i;
                    if (highlightStart > unchangedLength) highlightStart = unchangedLength;
                    if (highlightStart + highlightLength > unchangedLength) highlightLength = modifiedText.Length - highlightStart;
                    text = modifiedText.ToString();
                    break;
                }
        }
        finally
        {
            dc.ReleaseHdc();
        }



        // Find the end of the highlight first rather than the beginning. This avoids having to explicitly deal with kerning.
        // Kerning may move the first highlighted character closer to the previous character. As long as the two characters
        // are measured together, kerning is taken into consideration.
        // The rectangle extends to the full beginning of the highlighted text, even when kerning moves it. 
        var highlightXEnd = drawTextParams.iLeftMargin + TextRenderer.MeasureText(dc, text.Substring(0, highlightStart + highlightLength), font, bounds.Size, (flags & ~(PaddingFlags | AlignFlags | EllipsisFlags)) | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding).Width;

        // We don't care about the kerning of the first character *following* the highlight. This way the highlight is inclusive on both ends.
        // The rectangle extends to the full end of the highlighted text, regardless of how close the following character comes.
        var highlightSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(dc, text.Substring(highlightStart, highlightLength), font, bounds.Size, (flags & ~(PaddingFlags | AlignFlags | EllipsisFlags)) | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding);

        var unalignedHighlightBounds = new Rectangle(bounds.X + highlightXEnd - highlightSize.Width, bounds.Y, highlightSize.Width, highlightSize.Height);

        return ApplyAlignment(unalignedHighlightBounds, bounds.Width - totalSize.Width, bounds.Height - totalSize.Height, flags);
    }


    // Mimic TextRenderer's margins (see WindowsGraphics.GetTextMargins)
    private static User32.DRAWTEXTPARAMS GetTextMargins(Font font, TextFormatFlags flags)
    {
        var overhangPadding = font.Height / 6f;
        const float italicPaddingFactor = 0.5f;

        switch (flags & PaddingFlags)
        {
            case TextFormatFlags.GlyphOverhangPadding:
                return new User32.DRAWTEXTPARAMS(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(User32.DRAWTEXTPARAMS)))
                {
                    iLeftMargin = (int)Math.Ceiling(overhangPadding),
                    iRightMargin = (int)Math.Ceiling(overhangPadding * (1 + italicPaddingFactor))
                };
            case TextFormatFlags.LeftAndRightPadding:
                return new User32.DRAWTEXTPARAMS(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(User32.DRAWTEXTPARAMS)))
                {
                    iLeftMargin = (int)Math.Ceiling(overhangPadding * 2),
                    iRightMargin = (int)Math.Ceiling(overhangPadding * (2 + italicPaddingFactor))
                };
            case TextFormatFlags.NoPadding:
                return new User32.DRAWTEXTPARAMS(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(User32.DRAWTEXTPARAMS)))
                {
                    iLeftMargin = 0,
                    iRightMargin = 0
                };
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid combination of padding flags.", "flags");
        }
    }


    private static Rectangle ApplyAlignment(Rectangle rect, int widthDifference, int heightDifference, TextFormatFlags flags)
    {
        switch (flags & AlignFlags)
        {
            case TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left:
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter:
                rect.Offset(widthDifference / 2, 0);
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Right:
                rect.Offset(widthDifference, 0);
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Left:
                rect.Offset(0, heightDifference / 2);
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter:
                rect.Offset(widthDifference / 2, heightDifference / 2);
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.Right:
                rect.Offset(widthDifference, heightDifference / 2);
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Left:
                rect.Offset(0, heightDifference);
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter:
                rect.Offset(widthDifference / 2, heightDifference);
                break;
            case TextFormatFlags.Bottom | TextFormatFlags.Right:
                rect.Offset(widthDifference, heightDifference);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid combination of alignment flags.", "flags");
        }

        return rect;
    }

}
```